# Amazon Product Advertising API Scratchpad returning "MethodNotAllowed" every time

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to use the Amazon Product Advertising API. I have successfully used it before, but the Wordpress plugin I was using has stopped retrieving Amazon information, and seems to think my credentials are not valid.

I created a new Access Key / Secret Key pair (root, not IAM), but it still did not work.

I tried using the Amazon Product Advertising API Scratchpad with these new credentials, but no matter what I try I get an error "MethodNotAllowed".

I have a suspicion that my credentials are not valid, or that I've lost access to the product advertising API for some reason. However, when I try to sign-up again for Product Advertising API, I get told I've already got access.

I can't find any error messages or warnings in my AWS account.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well each API request to Amazon Product API requires a new signature. Here are the steps for calculating the signature for an API request: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html#rest-signature-examples

Comment: Thank you. I was actually only trying to use the Scratchpad, which creates the signature automatically. I have a feeling that the problem may have been one of propagation between Amazon servers, because when I came back to it later, it was working again.